# Split <INCLUDES> variable in CMAKE_[LANGUAGE]_COMPILE_OBJECT call

Tags: cmake, 65816

I got the following variable

```
set( CMAKE_CA65816_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_CA65816_COMPILER> --cpu 65816 -s -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE> -I <INCLUDES>")
```

This results in this command

```
ca65 --cpu 65816 -s -o Game.s.o Game.s -I include_dir1 include_dir2 include_dir3
```

But i need to repeat the **-I** parameter multiple times like this.

```
ca65 --cpu 65816 -s -o Game.s.o Game.s -I include_dir1 -I include_dir2 -I include_dir3
```

Is it possible to split the `<INCLUDES>` cmake variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is variable `CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_<LANG>` which denotes a flag to use with includes. You may also want to set `CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_<LANG>` variable to flag used with "system" includes (added with SYSTEM keyword).

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_FLAG_CA65816 "-I")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_SYSTEM_FLAG_CA65816 "-Isystem")
```